# PHP: Detect less than IE9 and ignore document and browser mode

Tags: php, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    FIXES (IE ONLY)
\*------------------------------------*/

if( preg_match( '/MSIE ([0-8].[0-9]{1,2})/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'respond', ( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/respond.min.js' ), false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'html5shiv', ( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/html5shiv.js' ), false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'selectivizr', ( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/selectivizr-min.js' ), array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

I currently use the above code in WordPress to detect IE under IE9. I do it this way because even if the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` is faked and they appear, it won't break normal browser behavior, so there's no need.

I need a way (in PHP) to detect if the browser is in compatibility mode (both browser and document mode IE8 (or less)).

http://dev.netcoding.net/sustain/

If you test that site out in a real IE8 browser, `respond.min.js` works perfectly fine. But when emulating IE8 by changing both Browser and Document mode in IE9-10, it causes the tab to crash.

I need a way to only add `respond.min.js` when it's the real IE8 browser, not an emulated one.

Comment: Note that your regex will match `MSIE 100`, should we ever get that far! This is because `.` is matching any character, because you didn't escape it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll write it in my 50 year todos. :)

Comment: Beware of browser detection. It is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is absolutely impossible to detect compatibility mode from the server-side. The only information you have available is the User Agent string, and that is identical between a real copy of IE7 and IE7-compatibility mode (or for whichever IE version you happen to be talking about).

In addition, since you specify that you're particularly looking to deal with people who change the mode using the Dev Tools, you will also be aware that there are two drop-boxes in the dev tools to set the mode: One of these changes the rendering mode, the other changes the UA string. This means that if you're dealing with someone who is setting the mode manually, then you can't even be sure that the UA string is reporting the same rendering mode that the user is actually using.

There are some techniques that may help you work out the mode in Javascript on the client, but even these are not always reliable.

In short, what you're asking for basically cannot be done.

However, I would argue that it *shouldn't* be done. Set the mode using the `X-UA-Compatible` flag, and leave it at that; users who are changing the mode manually should expect the site to break when they do so. It's not exactly part of a normal user's browsing behaviour anyway, so I really wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just disable compatibility mode:

```
header("X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge");
```

Or in the HTML source:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: My sites already add that header. It does not stop an individual from manually changing the document mode in F12 Developer Tools.

Comment: If they choose to manually break your site by using such a feature on purpose, then I would suggest giving them the same treatment as users who acively disable JavaScript: "screw you, I'm not wasting time because you choose to make my life difficult"

Comment: @BrianGraham If the user intentionally changes a *developer* setting, why bother?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem I was having.

`html5shiv` and/or `selectivizr` are interfering with `respond` at some point during page load.

I moved the loading of `respond.min.js` to be the very last script called on the page (in the footer), and it works with no problems (or flashing, as the developer assumed would happen).